# Como transformar Double em Binario Java

Tags: java, binary, double

Tentei fazer o metodo de transformar o resultado de um calculo assim ->

```
public String converteResultado(String resultado) {  
    return String.valueOf(Double.doubleToLongBits(Double.valueOf(resultado)));
}
```

O resultado são numeros Decimais, ex:(1.1 ou 0,12), eu pensei em transformar a String resultado em Double, depois transformar o Double em Binario, e depois transformar o Binario em String, e depois retornar o resultado em String, OBS: tenho que retornar um resultado em String.

Comment: de uma olhada neste link, está em espanhol, mas é compreensível: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32796/c%C3%B3mo-pasar-de-decimal-a-binario-en-java

Answer (score 0):

Fiz o seguinte teste e funcionou bem

```
String i =  Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(1.1D));
System.out.println(i);
```

retornou `11111111110001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010`